# Links not working because of background image

Tags: html, css

for some reason my links aren't clickable. I'm guessing it's because of the background because when I take it off they work. But I'm not sure why exactly that is. The background is set in css:

```
div::after {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(brain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.1;
}

nav.horizontal li {
    width: 10.66%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
}


nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
}
```

The html for the navigation:

```
<nav class="horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
        <li><a href="formpage1.html">Quiz page 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Need your HTML also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::after` might be blocking the clicks, try adding `pointer-events: none;` here `div::after {...}`

```
div::after {
  pointer-events: none;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;


  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background: url(brain.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your styles to "div" not to "div::after"

Prefer snippet:

```css
div {

  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;


  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
   background: url('https://cdn.britannica.com/s:300x300/07/1907-004-5162F5E4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.5; 

}


nav.horizontal li {
    width: 10.66%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;

}


nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    margin-right: 19px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div>

        <nav class="horizontal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
                <li><a href="formpage1.html">Quiz page 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        
</div>
```